# Best way to maintain multiple copies of Database

Tags: sql

We have a database in SQL,let's say it is Employers DB. There is an application which inserts and updates the records in Employers DB. Approximately 4 times a year we will release this DB to our users. Currently we ave 10 copies of Employers DBs

EmployersDB_01/07/2014,
EmployersDB_04/07/2014,
EmployersDB_07/07/2014,
EmployersDB_09/07/2014,
.
.
.
.
etc

This list will grow in future. We want to save all these database copies in global server. Database team who works on that server said that we can't save like this. 
But we want to save these databases  like individual copies because there is another application which connects to these copies. Say like the application want to see data in the period 01/07/2014 they have to connect to the EmployersDB_01/07/2014 database.

How can I do this as IT team can't save these many copies of DBs. All these databases have almost same tables but data is different.

PS: I am newbie to this programming and excuse me if my questions is not clear enough. Let me know so that I will explain in comments section. Before you answer please give explanation to any technical words that you use. Please don't give negative votes, let me know if something is not right.

Comment: I don't really see how this is a C# question. Removed tag.

Comment: Best way to do it would be to have your `DBA` do it perhaps `Replication Server` also perhaps you can get into something like `TFS` where you can at least manage your Server Builds and Scripts

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am one responsible to do this job. But we need to migrate them to server as another C# application needs to access them via connection strings. So TFS is out of picture for us. These are all redtape things in our IT. Thanks for ur input though.

Comment: are you a DBA..? I think that you are mixing and matching .. C# Application has nothing to do with Databases and how many you have .. I think that you may be in above your head.. consult with a DBA
another thought.. are you familiar with `VMWare`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am a developer. In my present job I have to work on this SQL DB related issue. There is no resources who can help me with this and thats why I posted this question in forum. Not familiar with VMware, will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concerns with saving multiple DB copies to a server. To me it would be most likely a concern of size. If the databases are large or if you are getting a sufficiently large number of the databases the size on the disk could make your hardware unstable. On top of that their would be concerns of overtaxing the software if your database team was working on many of the databases at the same time. This could cause stress on the server hardware as well. There isn't necessarily a software reason you *could not* store all of the copies of your databases on a central server, you would be running into serious hardware issues.

Comment: I got it that it is not a way to go. Can you please suggest some alternates. Databases should be in the server and should be accesible to C# application via connection string. How about schemas, not sure if I can connect to schemas to C# via connection string. Thanks for ur input.

Comment: The way we handled it in my last project is that each developer kept a local copy of the database they were working in on their develop box and connected to it via a connection string. We kept backups of each data base on a central server that we could retrieve and restore locally when we needed to work in a database. This helps alleviate the taxing of the server's memory, but doesn't greatly mitigate storage concerns.